# Why the webpack config do not work?

Tags: webpack

I just want to extract vendor from common chunk, but the following config do not work. What's the correct config?

```js
entry: {
        vendor: ['vue', 'vuex', 'vue-router', 'vuex-router-sync','vue-resource']
}
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name:'common',
      minChunks: function (module, count) {
        return (
          module.resource &&
          /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
          module.resource.indexOf(
            path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
          ) === 0
        )
      }
}),
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'vendor',
    chunks:['vendor','common']
})
```

Comment: Is this fragments of your webpack config or full your config? Plugins must be specified in plugins section at least.

Comment: it is fragments of my config

Comment: What exactly do not work? You see an error or results are different from what you expect? Full config might help.

Comment: no errors, but the common contains all chunks, the vendor only 1 KB size, not contain the chunks in entry